# How long is Spring temporary CSRF token expiration time?

Tags: spring, session, csrf

I enabled CSRF with spring security and it is working as expected.

I read Spring official documentation about CSRF
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf

I also read this tutorial about CSRF with Spring and AngularJS
http://www.codesandnotes.be/2015/07/24/angularjs-web-apps-for-spring-based-rest-services-security-the-server-side-part-2-csrf/

> What Spring Security does is that it sets up a temporary session for
>   that. So basically it goes like this:
>
> 1. The client asks a token with an OPTIONS request.
> 2. The server creates a temporary session, stores the token and sends back a JSESSIONID and the token to the client.
> 3. The client submits the login credentials using that JSESSIONID and CSRF token.
> 4. The server matches the CSRF stored for the received JSESSIONID and, if all is green-lighted, creates a new definitive JSESSIONID and a new session-based CSRF token for the client to validate its requests after the login.

As I have understood, when you are not logged in, you can get your first CSRF token by sending an OPTIONS request on any API endpoint, for example /api/login

Spring will then create a CSRF token bound to a temporary session (temporary CSRF and JSESSIONID cookies)

Thus, if I ask the CSRF token than wait a few minutes and finally try to login, the CSRF token may have expîred and I will have to ask another one.

**I couldn't find how to configure the temporary Spring session expiration time and I couldn't find what was its exact default duration.**

Does anyone has any information about that ?

Answer (score 8):

> creates a new definitive JSESSIONID and a new session-based CSRF token

this is a [session fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation) strategy.

there are at least 2 strategies for CSRFToken generation.

1. [per session](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/22936/43366)
2. [per request](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/22923/43366)

The default behaviour [should be](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-timeouts) `per session`. It means that as long as session would be `alive` one and only CSRFToken would be bound to it (but this can be changed).
after successful authentication, because of session fixation, a new session would be created with new CSRFToken.

> Thus, if I ask the CSRF token than wait a few minutes and finally try
>   to login, the CSRF token may have expîred and I will have to ask
>   another one

this is wrong. it would stay as long as session would be active.

> I couldn't find how to configure the temporary Spring session
>   expiration time and I couldn't find what was its exact default
>   duration

`temporary session` is called `temporary`, because it would be valid until authentication and would be replaced by a new one. But same timeout policy is applied to them as for `common` session. you can configure `session-timeout` in `web.xml` using `session-config`. the default value of `Tomcat` is 30 minutes.

Comment: Thank you but it seems that you are wrong, because I have configured the session to last 24 hours (1440 min in web.xml). When I am authenticated, it effectively lasts 24 hours, so it's fine. However when I am not authenticated, the session only lasts for a few minutes, so there must be something else, maybe an hardcorded timeout for unauthenticated sessions.

Comment: @singe3 I have a few questions: 1) have you done anything to spring config? 2) how JSESSIONID and CSRFToken are returned from a server (as cookie (what is exp time) and/or response body)?

Comment: No I didn't change spring default config about csrf token. I solved my problem in the front-end by making an OPTIONS request on the login endpoint just before the login POST in order to retrieve a fresh token. My token is sent to the client as a custom header because It's cross domain so I can't read a cookie from Javascript.